# Apex/Oracle: When creating a new page, the tables I've created won't show up

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am creating an application in Oracle for a piece of coursework.

I've been using it for a few weeks and have just come across an issue;

I need to submit this on friday, and it's a mess, so I created a new application and tried to add a new page, but none of the tables that I have created are available to choose... I've tried dropping all my previous tables and objects etc. and then re-inserted everything back in. My SQL queries etc work fine. 
All of my tables appear in the SQL Browser. I've even tried creating a new application a few times and trying different combinations of thing, but to no avail.

I have searched and searched google and online help for Oracle etc, but with no results

I am using my Universitys local oracle apex, but this is happening on the normal apex as well....

Any help would be appreciated... freaking out as this is due in less than 2 days!

Comment: did you added the schema through the apex admin page to the workspace?

Comment: How do I do that? I've been using this in class for a few weeks but haven't needed to do that before as far as i know? - we're signed in as an Administrator, using sql cmds

Comment: check this out: http://www.oraclenerd.com/2009/12/apex-assign-multiple-schemas-to-single.html

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at it in the morning.... (it's after 2am)

Comment: oh i see...not so urgent after all...

Comment: I doubt OP will have access to the internal workspace though if they've simply been provided. Did you check the application's assigned parsing schema? In SQL browser or commands, can you select another schema (top right, select list) ?

Comment: @Tom - no, I can't select another Schema.

Comment: Ok, so in trying to determine the problem: can you check under `Shared Components > Security > Security Attributes > Database Schema`. What is assigned and is it correct?

Comment: It's okay, I had sent an email to my lecturer and he replied there to say that it's because it's a table that's referencing an object - so I have to extract it using SQL - I am so sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting one of my lectures, he informed me that as I am referencing an object table, that they won't show up on the drop down list - you need to reference it using SQL instead